# Ubuntu 22: Windows Moving Under Dock

Tags: dock

Windows have been moving underneath the dock (see attached photo).

I can consistently reproduce the effect by having a maximized window open, locking the screen, and then unlocking it.

[Example of the dock overlapping with firefox after locking and unlocking my system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZift.png)

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and Gnome version 42.9. If any other information is helpful please let me know.

I understand this is a duplicate issue but the others have no solution and no steps to reproduce. Without reputation I can't comment steps to reproduce on these posts, so I'm making my own.

Comment: Great question (I have the same problem), it only misses links to the duplicates. I only found https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2490510 (haven't searched for long)

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure it's a bug and should be reported as such: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work around this issue by using the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh

dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver'" |
  while read x; do
    case "$x" in 
      *"boolean true"*)
         echo SCREEN_LOCKED;;
      *"boolean false"*)
         echo SCREEN_UNLOCKED
         gnome-extensions disable ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
         sleep 0.5
         gnome-extensions enable ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
    esac
  done
```

Name it something like fix_dock.sh, add it to "Startup Applications". Whenever the screen locks and then "unlocks", it will disable the dock, wait half a second and then re-enable it. This should realign the windows.

Comment: Seems to be working, I'll try to come back to confirm in a few days. After creating the file I executed `chmod +x fix_dock.sh`, I think it's necessary for the script to execute. Also, I still think this bug should be reported to Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes you're right, You need to make it executable by running the above command.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work properly, some windows still slip under the dock. :(

Comment: I think the window which are minimized when the dock is disabled/re-anabled aren't affected. Maybe you could modify this script so that every window is maximized before?